# Bandwidth ttcp and PCTTCP

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, winsock, winsock2

I have a very amusing problem with Winsock programming. To be honest: I’m not amused about this.

My target is to test the bandwidth of a GBit Network. I connected a PC with a GBit-Network card (Windows 7 64 bit) with an embedded system (which includes also a GBit network chip).

The embed system works as a UDP Server (Don’t ask me details, it is FPGA programming stuff).
From the website http://www.pcausa.com/Utilities/ttcpdown1.htm I downloaded the PCATTCP tool.

The tool PCATTCP I run it with the following options:

```
 PCATTCP.exe -t -l 1178  -u -p XYZ -f m -s A.B.C.D <MyBinaryFile.bin
```

(The port number XYZ and the ip address are not important in this case)
The result is that the bandwidth is around 150 Mbit/s.

On the PC there is the cygwin (64 bit) environment installed, where the tool ttcp is included.
So I started ttcp with:

```
ttcp -t -l 1178  -u -p XYZ -f m A.B.C.D <MyBinaryFile.bin
```

And here we have around 600 Mbit/s.
Is this realy true? The Cygwin’s ttcp is faster than the pure winsock calls from PCATTCP???
To be sure on this I started Wireshark. And yes the time column in Wireshark tells me, that the ttcp tool is faster than PCATTCP.
Furthermore I run ttcp with this options:

```
ttcp -t -l 1178 –b 1178 -u -p XYZ -f m A.B.C.D <MyBinaryFile.bin
```

Then the bandwidth is nearly the same like PCATTCP (around 150 Mbit/s).
The ‘b’ option is to set the socket buffer size. But it has not effect with the PCATTCP tool.

In this case I have the following questions:
How Cygwin does communicate? Does it use windsock?

Why takes it not effect if I change the socket buffer size with the PCATTCP tool?

Does anybody have suggestion about this case?

Greetings,

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

I find some information, how cygwin works with sockets:

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/highlights.html

There is this text:

Socket-related calls in Cygwin basically call the functions by the same name in Winsock, Microsoft's implementation of Berkeley sockets, but with lots of tweaks. All sockets are non-blocking under the hood to allow to interrupt blocking calls by POSIX signals. Additional bookkeeping is necessary to implement correct socket sharing POSIX semantics and especially for the select call.

This means the method "sendto(...)" is under cygwin asynchrony and with PCATTCP synchrony.

And if you want the best performance of the network, you have to implement the sockets asynchrony; Boost::Asio (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) contains such asynchrony methods (e.g. “async_send_to”).

Unfortunately I couldn’t figure out why changing the buffer socket size with the PCATTCP tool has no effect.

Regards,

Thomas